# Exsitence of bounded, non-periodic, infinite recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Does there exist an infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,\ldots$ of real numbers which is bounded, not periodic, and satisfies the recursion $a_{n+1}=a_na_{n-1}+1$?

Comment: If this sequence has a limit $L$ then $L=L^2+1$, but this equation has no real solution, so if it there exists, it must have at least two accumulation points.

Comment: It is easy to show also that $a_1a_2<0$.